# How do I attach the image result from my API call as the background image to my app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, api

So background on what I'm trying to do.. User inputs city and the background changes to an image of that city, an image that is acquired from an API call to the Pixabay API. I have held the result as the variable "background" but I can't figure out how to append it to the background of the page. The "const background" variable itself renders an image URL. Meaning that when I console.log(background) I get the URL for the background image that I want to apply to the entire page.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Title from "./Title.js";
import Form from "./Form.js";
import Weather from "./Weather.js";
import axios from "axios";

// import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

const API_KEY = "b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";
// const API_ID = "12653279-f2ae53f8bfb342d39b6cbf92b";

class App extends Component {
  // the initial state of the application is set below, will change upon submit of button
  state = {
    temperature: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    error: undefined,
    searchText: "",
    apiUrl: "https://pixabay.com/api",
    apiKey: "12653279-f2ae53f8bfb342d39b6cbf92b",
    images: []
  };
  getweatherData = async e => {
    // arrow function used as an alternative to constructor to bind data and use "this" to still be bound to component
    // async returns a promsise to be settled
    e.preventDefault();
    // e argument passed in the async function is now used to prevent refresh default action
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    // a way that we can make the city value dynamic within the api url in the api call
    const api_call = await fetch(
      // await key word pauses the function until data is recieved from api call
      `https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}`
    );
    const data = await api_call.json();
    // above, the data recieved from the API is converted to json readable format
    console.log(data);
    if (data.cod === 404) {
      throw Error(data.message);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        temperature: data.main.temp.toFixed(0),
        city: data.sys.city,
        country: data.sys.country,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error: "undefined"
      });
    }
    axios
      .get(
        `${this.state.apiUrl}/?key=${
          this.state.apiKey
        }&q=${city}&image_type=photo&per_page="1"
        }&safesearch=true&editorschoice= true`
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ images: res.data.hits });
        const background = res.data.hits[1];
        console.log(background);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Title />
        {/* setting up a prop to the getweatherData value so we can have access to it in the form.js */}
        <Form getweatherData={this.getweatherData} />
        {/* defining props so they can be accessed in the weather.js */}
        <Weather
          temperature={this.state.temperature}
          city={this.state.city}
          country={this.state.country}
          description={this.state.description}
          error={this.state.error}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Form. js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // a react attribute onSubmit to call in our prop
      <form onSubmit={this.props.getweatherData}>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City..." />
        {/* <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country..." /> */}
        <button>Get Weather</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: you are trying to change the background of this element  `<div className="container">` ?  and is the result of background is a url?

Answer (score 1):

Set the background image in state, and then use inline style on your whatever element you want it to be displayed in. Something like this.

```
...
const background = res.data.hits[1];
this.setState({ background })
...
return (
    <div className="container" style={{ this.state.background ? { background: this.state.background } : {} }}>
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, the background variable itself is an image URL. Meaning that when I console.log(background) I get the URL for the background image that I want to apply to the entire page, I'm not understanding what the ? marks are referring to

Comment: I just put the dots there to make it clearer which parts that you need to change. You got the image url in a variable after you've fetched it from your API. Take this variable and set it in state, so you can access it in your render function. In your render function, you access it through your state object, and then you apply it by using the style prop.